# New Relic Api Fetching Monitoring Details

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, monitoring, newrelic

Can we fetch the uptime and downtime details of my application from NewRelic Rest API. Didn't find any method in API. 
    http://newrelic.github.com/newrelic_api/
Is there any other way we can do that, if not from new relic?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can't get availability monitoring data via our REST API. 'Dashboard HTML Fragment' will include this information, but not in an ideal format :( 
We are working on improving this system in the near future.